# Ways to optimize MySQL table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a big big table the size of table is in GB's around 130 GB. Every day data is dumped in the table.

I'd like to optimize the table... Can anyone suggest me how I should go about it?

Any input will be a great help.

Comment: Delete half the records? Seriously, if you want a serious response, I think you will need to add more info.

Comment: @DBA show us the `create table` statement and some queries that you want to speed up.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..pekka and Johan. @Pekka - well actually I cannot delete anything as I need the data. @Johan - Well the data is so much that I cannot even how many rows are there in that table. but its in billions....The table has been created in InnoDB storage engine. there are 6 indexes on the table in which one is composite index.

Comment: Maybe you can't delete but does it all need to be stored in the same table? The only reason for optimizing a table is so the queries run faster - but you've not provided any details of the queries you are currently running nor the structure of the table, nor the pattern of usage.

Comment: well for optimizing my sole purpose is not increasing query performance. As When I am trying to fire a query on this particular table to get all the data i mean select * or select Count(*). The mysql server goes away.

Comment: To answer this question, we need to see more about your table. Without more information "minimize rows, columns, and indexes" is the best answer. Make sure that any poorly-performing queries have a corresponding index.

Answer (score 4):

It depends how you are trying to optimize it.

For querying speed, appropriate indexes including multi-column indexes would be a very good place to start.  Do explains on all your queries to see what is taking up so much time.  Optimize the code that's reading the data to store it instead of requerying.

If old data is less important or you're getting too much data to handle, you can rotate tables by year, month, week, or day.  That way the data writing is always to a pretty minimal table.  The older tables are all dated (ie tablefoo_2011_04) so that you have a backlog.

If you are trying to optimize size in the same table, make sure you are using appropriate types.  If you get variable length strings, use a varchar instead of statically sized data.  Don't use strings for status indicators, use an enum or int with a secondary lookup table.

The server should have a lot of ram so that it's not going to disk all the time.

You can also look at using a caching layer such as memcached.

More information about what the actual problem is, your situation, and what you are trying to optimize for would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Evan, Thanks for scuh detail explanation. Well, yes old data is important but I can separate it from current table. and store it in year wise table. but still a year has a hell lot of data....there are indexes on place. in a day around close to million records are getting inserted. right now modifing a table design is it a good idea..won't it corrupt the data?

Comment: It depends on the changes that you are making.  For any sort of table modifications you should always make a backup first.  If a year is too long, you can go to month tables or even day tables if need be. The safest thing to do is to create a new column of the right type.  Then update columns so the new column equals the original.  Then verify the data is correct.  Then remove the original column.  You can write up your update to convert data in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score 2):

If your table is a sort of logging table, there can be several strategy for optimizing.

(1) Store essential data only.

- If there are not necessary - nullable - columns in it and they does not be used for aggregation or analytics, store them into other table. Keep the main table smaller.
- Ex) Don't store raw HTTP_USER_AGENT string. Preprocessing the agent string and store smaller data what you exactly want to review.

(2) Make the table as fixed format.

- Use CHAR then VARCHAR for almost-fixed-length strings. This will be helpful for sped up SELECT queries.
- Ex) ip VARCHAR(15) => ip CHAR(15)

(3) Summarize old data and dump them into other table periodically.

- If you don't have to review the whole data everyday, divide it into periodically table (year/month/day) and store summarize data for old ones.
- Ex) Table_2011_11 / Table_2011_11_28

(4) Don't use too many indexes for big table.

- Too many indexes cause heavy load for inserting queries.

(5) Use ARCHIVE engine.

- MySQL supports ARCHIVE ENGINE. This engine supports zlib for data compression.
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html
- It fits for logging generally(AFAIK), lack of ORDER BY, REPLACE, DELETE and UPDATE are not a big problem for logging.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us what your SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename outputs so we can see the columns, indexes and so on.

From the glimpse of everything, it seems MySQL's [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) is what you need to implement in order to increase performance further.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible strategies.

If the dataset is so large, it may be of use to store certain information redundantly: keeping cache tables if certain records are accessed much more frequently than others, denormalize information (either to limit the number of joins or creating tables with less columns so you have a lean table to keep in memory at all times), or keeping summaries for the fast lookup of totals.

The summaries-table(s) can be kept in synch by either periodically generating them or by the use of triggers, or even combining both by having a cache table for the latest day on which you can calculate actual totals, and summaries for the historical data... will give you full precision while not requiring to read the full index. Test to see what delivers best performance in your situation.

Splitting your table by periods is certainly an option. It's like partitioning, but [Mayflower Blog](http://blog.mayflower.de/archives/353-Is-MySQL-partitioning-useful-for-very-big-real-life-problems.html) advises to do it yourself as the MySQL implementation seems to have certain limitations.

Additionally to this: if the data in those historical tables is never changed and you want to reduce space, you could use [myisampack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisampack.html). Indexes are supported (you have to rebuild) and performance gain is reported, but I suspect you would gain speed on reading individual rows but face decreasing performance on large reads (as lots of rows need unpacking).

And last: you could think about what you need from the historical data. Does it need the exact same information you have for more recent entries, or are there things that just aren't important anymore? I could imagine if you have an access log, for example, that it stores all sorts of information like ip, referal url, requested url, user agent... Perhaps in 5 years time the user agent isn't interesting at all to know, it's fine to combine all requests from one ip for one page + css + javascript + images into one entry (perhaps have a different many-to-one table for the precise files), and the referal urls only need number of occurances and can be decoupled from exact time or ip.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to consider the speed of the medium on which the data is stored. I think you can use raid disks to speed up access or maybe store the table in RAM but at 130GB that might be a challenge! Then consider the processor too. I realise this isn't a direct answer to your question but it may help achieve your aims.

Answer (score 0):

You can still try to do partitioning using tablespaces or "table-per-period" structure as @Evan advised.

If your fulltext searching is failing may be should go to Sphinx/Lucene/Solr. External search engines can definitely help you to get faster.

If we are talking about table structure than you should use the smallest datatype if it possible.
If `optimize table` is too slow and it's true for the really big tables you can backup this table and restore it. Off course in this case you will need to get some downtime.

As bottom line:
if your issue concerning fulltext searching than before applying any table changes try to use external search engines.